# is there a better way to handle index.html with Tornado?

Tags: python, tornado

I want to know if there is a better way to handle my index.html file with Tornado.

I use StaticFileHandler for all the request,and use a specific MainHandler to handle my main request. If I only use StaticFileHandler I got a 403: Forbidden error

```
GET http://localhost:9000/
WARNING:root:403 GET / (127.0.0.1):  is not a file
```

here how I doing now:

```py
import os
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
from  tornado import web

__author__ = 'gvincent'

root = os.path.dirname(__file__)
port = 9999

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        try:
            with open(os.path.join(root, 'index.html')) as f:
                self.write(f.read())
        except IOError as e:
            self.write("404: Not Found")

application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/", MainHandler),
    (r"/(.*)", web.StaticFileHandler, dict(path=root)),
    ])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    application.listen(port)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Comment: It would be better to replace `r"/"` and `r"/(.*)"`  with  `r"/$"` and `r"/(.*)$"`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Turns out that Tornado's StaticFileHandler already includes *default filename* functionality.

Feature was added in Tornado release 1.2.0:
 https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/commit/638a151d96d681d3bdd6ba5ce5dcf2bd1447959c

To specify a default file name you need to set the "default_filename" parameter as part of the WebStaticFileHandler initialization.

Updating your example:

```
import os
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

root = os.path.dirname(__file__)
port = 9999

application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/(.*)", tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {"path": root, "default_filename": "index.html"})
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    application.listen(port)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

This handles root requests:

- `/` -> `/index.html`

sub-directory requests:

- `/tests/` -> `/tests/index.html`

and appears to correctly handle redirects for directories, which is nice:

- `/tests` -> `/tests/index.html`

Comment: Can i use the templating tags with these .html files?

Comment: This took me about 5 hours to actually found this amazing answer, a thousand thanks!

Answer (score 12):

Thanks to the previous answer, here is the solution I prefer:

```python
import Settings
import tornado.web
import tornado.httpserver


class Application(tornado.web.Application):
    def __init__(self):
        handlers = [
            (r"/", MainHandler)
        ]
        settings = {
            "template_path": Settings.TEMPLATE_PATH,
            "static_path": Settings.STATIC_PATH,
        }
        tornado.web.Application.__init__(self, handlers, **settings)


class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render("index.html")


def main():
    applicaton = Application()
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(applicaton)
    http_server.listen(9999)

    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And Settings.py

```python
import os
dirname = os.path.dirname(__file__)

STATIC_PATH = os.path.join(dirname, 'static')
TEMPLATE_PATH = os.path.join(dirname, 'templates')
```

Comment: can your changes to `index.html` be seen with just refreshing the browser and without restarting the app?

Comment: @xuan i don't understand what you want me to do ?

Comment: sorry, should be more clear. say during developing your app, you make changes to `index.html`, and you want to see the changes from your browser. if `index.html` is a rendered template rather than a static file, can you see the changes with just refreshing the page?

Comment: with tornado.autoreload certainly : http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/autoreload.html

Comment: pay attention to the ABSOLUTE path,not a relative static path!

Answer (score 5):

Use this code instead

```
class IndexDotHTMLAwareStaticFileHandler(tornado.web.StaticFileHandler):
    def parse_url_path(self, url_path):
        if not url_path or url_path.endswith('/'):
            url_path += 'index.html'

        return super(IndexDotHTMLAwareStaticFileHandler, self).parse_url_path(url_path)
```

now use that class instead of vanilla StaticFileHandler in your Application... job's done!

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to explicitly add a `StaticFileHandler`; just specify the static_path and it will serve those pages.

You are correct that you need a MainHandler, as for some reason Tornado will not serve the `index.html` file, even if you append the filename to the URL.

In that case, this slight modification to your code should work for you:

```
import os
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
from tornado import web

__author__ = 'gvincent'

root = os.path.dirname(__file__)
port = 9999

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render("index.html")

application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/", MainHandler),
    ], template_path=root,
    static_path=root)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    application.listen(port)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Comment: I can't serve *.html file in my root folder with this solution. I need a handler for those files too.

Comment: What version of Tornado are you using? I tested both your original and my answer, and each can serve arbitrary *.html files. I am using Tornado `version = "2.4.post1"`, `version_info = (2, 4, 0, 1)` (found in `__init__.py`).

Comment: version = "2.4.1"
version_info = (2, 4, 1, 0) I use the same version

Comment: These are mapped to /static/

Answer (score 4):

I have been trying this. Don't use render it has additional overhead of parsing templates and gives error on template type strings in static html. I found this is the simplest way. Tornado is looking for a capturing parenthesis in regex , just give it an empty capturing group.

```
import os
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

root = os.path.dirname(__file__)
port = 9999

application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/()", tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {"path": root, "default_filename": "index.html"})
])
```

This has effect of resolving / to index.html and also avoid unwanted resolves like /views.html to static_dir/views.html

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me [From the tornado docs](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.StaticFileHandler):

> To serve a file like `index.html` automatically when a directory is requested, set `static_handler_args=dict(default_filename="index.html")` in your application settings, or add `default_filename` as an initializer argument for your `StaticFileHandler`.